Oil seals need changing
I have a Nissan (Terrano / Pathfinder) Vg30 V6 petrol engine with 180k kilometers on it and the front and rear oil seals are starting to seep a little oil. Can these seals be changed by just dropping the sump case, or is there more involved.
Thankyou.
